# DeCorrelated SubQueries in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been struggling with a problem for hours. I have found myself down multiple rabbit holes and into the realms of DeCorrelated SubQueries which are frankly beyond me...

I have two tables and I'm trying to pull from both without a common column to join against. I need to take the a value from table 1, find the closest value (that is lower) in table 2 and then pull related data from table 2.

table_1

| id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99.983545 |
| 2 | 98.674359 |
| 3 | 97.832475 |
| 4 | 96.184545 |
| 5 | 93.658572 |
| 6 | 89.963544 |
| 7 | 87.427353 |
| 8 | 82.883345 |

table_2

| average_level | percentile |
| --- | --- |
| 99.743545 | 99 |
| 97.994359 | 98 |
| 97.212485 | 97 |
| 96.987545 | 96 |
| 95.998573 | 95 |
| 88.213584 | 94 |
| 87.837384 | 93 |
| 80.982147 | 92 |

From the two tables above I need to:

1. Take the id and score
2. identify the closest average_level to the score
3. include the correlating average_level and percentile

The hoped for output would look like this...

| id | score | average_level | percentile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99.983545 | 99.743545 | 99 |
| 2 | 98.674359 | 97.994359 | 98 |
| 3 | 97.832475 | 97.212485 | 97 |
| 4 | 96.184545 | 95.998573 | 95 |
| 5 | 93.658572 | 88.213584 | 94 |
| 6 | 89.963544 | 88.213584 | 94 |
| 7 | 87.427353 | 80.982147 | 92 |
| 8 | 82.883345 | 80.982147 | 92 |

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by joining both tables with table_1.score >= table_2.average_level and then getting the max(average_level) and max(average_level) - which will be the closest yet inferior or equal values from table_2 - and grouping by the fields in table_1:

```
SELECT TABLE_1.ID, TABLE_1.SCORE, 
MAX(TABLE_2.AVERAGE_LEVEL) AS AVERAGE_LEVEL, 
MAX(TABLE_2.PERCENTILE) AS PERCENTILE
FROM TABLE_1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2
ON TABLE_1.SCORE >= TABLE_2.AVERAGE_LEVEL
GROUP BY TABLE_1.ID, TABLE_1.SCORE
ORDER BY TABLE_1.ID
```

I add the fiddle example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f1c8659eb032bd5da907dd9e2023d04a), it also includes @Ömer's answer

Comment: This would generate too many rows per score, e.g. score of 98 will be joined with all averages less than/equal to 98. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

if we say first table **score**
and second one **avarage**
you can try this.

```
select *
from Score s
inner join average a on a.Percentile = (select top(1) al.Percentile from average al order by Abs(average_level - s.score))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Ghb.png)